# Using special characters when building a text string in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a complex string to insert a new formulae on the fly in google script.  In VBA you use chr(34), is there a similar work around in google script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From this thread "[Some common VBA functions translated to Google Apps Script](http://www.slideshare.net/BruceMcPherson1/vbagasprimer)" you will find here in Slide 6 that the `function Chr(n)` in VBA is translated in the javascript:

```
 function Chr(n) {
  return String.fromCharCode(n);
}
```

You can also find it in this [Github](https://gist.github.com/brucemcpherson/3358690).

For the sample code on how to use this function in AppsScript, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder).

```
var map = Maps.newStaticMap();
 for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
   var leg = route.legs[i];
   if (i == 0) {
     // Add a marker for the start location of the first leg only.
     map.setMarkerStyle(markerSize, markerColor, String.fromCharCode(markerLetterCode));
     map.addMarker(leg.start_location.lat, leg.start_location.lng);
     markerLetterCode++;
   }
   map.setMarkerStyle(markerSize, markerColor, String.fromCharCode(markerLetterCode));
   map.addMarker(leg.end_location.lat, leg.end_location.lng);
   markerLetterCode++;
 }
```